# Getting average of distinct list values

Tags: python, list

I have 4k values in list created from first col of this dataset ([link](https://gist.github.com/karimkhanp/1692f1f76718c35e939f)):

```
11 1
19 1
42 2
16 1
63 3
14 1
11 1
83 4
63 3
11 1
13 1
17 1
92 4
11 2
86 2
```

and so on

I want to convert first column in distinct list along with average value of it's corresonding 2nd value.

Approach 1: looping through last line and checking condition if similar value then increment count and add value in 2nd col. At the end divide by count

Apprach 2: convert col1 into list

`col1 = list(set(col1))` which will give distinct values for `col1` but how do I get average of 2nd col for each distinct value in first col?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, supposed you have [**Pandas**](http://pandas.pydata.org/) installed, it will be a straight forward [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) with [mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html), like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = '''11 1
19 1
42 2
16 1
63 3
14 1
11 1
83 4
63 3
11 1
13 1
17 1
92 4
11 2
86 2 '''
# using your sample data
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(s), header=None, sep=' ')    

df
Out[5]: 
     0  1
0   11  1
1   19  1
2   42  2
3   16  1
4   63  3
5   14  1
6   11  1
7   83  4
8   63  3
9   11  1
10  13  1
11  17  1
12  92  4
13  11  2
14  86  2
```

Using `groupby` to group the column `0` which is the first-column values, and they will be distinct, then `mean` will apply to column `1` to calculate their relative average values:

```
df.groupby(0).mean()
Out[6]: 
       1
0       
11  1.25
13  1.00
14  1.00
16  1.00
17  1.00
19  1.00
42  2.00
63  3.00
83  4.00
86  2.00
92  4.00
```

*As a side note*: **Pandas** `read_table()`, `read_csv()` etc etc. can read from both file path and file buffer. My sample above is merely using an in-memory buffer.

Comment: interesting, what you considered `s` here? IF I read file content and put it in `s` that is also fine?

Comment: @MobinShaikh, `s` is barely a string with your sample in it. In Pandas, you can read the file/path directly, ie. `pd.read_table(your_file_or_path, ...)`, you can also use `read_csv` etc.

Comment: dont have enough point to upvote your answer : ( could you please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149766/normalizing-matrix-values-python-r

Comment: @MobinShaikh, I have added `s` back to the code so won't be so confused to you, also a side note for what formats pandas `read_*` can accept. Given your dataset structure it's really meant for some data analysis, give Pandas a try and you will like it.

Comment: @learner, let me take a look. `fillna` is indeed the right way to go about it. But the answer has been missing on *HOW* to fill the na.

Comment: yeah that is the main issue about filling missing value, I was thinking of averaging the neighbouring value, but not sure how appealing this approach is

Comment: @learner, if that dataset1 only missing values are `1`, you can also just try locating the `1` in that dataset and replace with relevant dataset2 mean values as my answer posted. Let me check that out later and perhaps to post an answer to stackexchange

Comment: thanks a lot, replacing 1 with mean of which value from dataset2?

Comment: @learner, I just looked at the sample data, there is no `1` in it? also if the value is `1`, how do you want to replace from dataset2? <-- I mean there is no value to follow

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, I udpated the question. `0` is with missing value, I took 1-100 rather 0-99

Comment: @learner, sorry I was zzz... and I realized I haven't got a `stats` account. anyway I've posted an answer there and hopefully will help you get started. I have to go to bed now :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest building a `defaultdict()` using the first-column value as the key, and a list of values from the second column.  Then loop over your `defaultdict` and compute the average values.

Like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = (int(x) for x in line.split())
        d[key].append(value)

def mean(lst):
    if not lst: return 0
    return float(sum(lst)) / len(lst)

mean_values = {key: mean(lst) for key, lst in d.iteritems()}
```